# PHP Check which user is logged in

Tags: php, html, authentication, admin, registration

We are creating a website for a school project and need an admin user.
The plan is to check which user is logged in. The check is done with the name.
For e.g. username is "admin@xxx.xx" when this user is logged in it should a other site as a other user.

Is this possible?

Registration.php`enter code here`

```
<?php 
session_start();
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydb11', 'root', '');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head>
  <title>Registrierung</title>    
</head> 
<body>
 
<?php
$showFormular = true; //Variable ob das Registrierungsformular anezeigt werden soll
 
if(isset($_GET['register'])) {
    $error = false;
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $passwort = $_POST['passwort'];
    $passwort2 = $_POST['passwort2'];
    
  
    if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        echo 'Bitte eine gültige E-Mail-Adresse eingeben<br>';
        $error = true;
    }     
    if(strlen($passwort) == 0) {
        echo 'Bitte ein Passwort angeben<br>';
        $error = true;
    }
    if($passwort != $passwort2) {
        echo 'Die Passwörter müssen übereinstimmen<br>';
        $error = true;
    }
    
    //Überprüfe, dass die E-Mail-Adresse noch nicht registriert wurde
    if(!$error) { 
        $statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = :email");
        $result = $statement->execute(array('email' => $email));
        $user = $statement->fetch();
        
        if($user !== false) {
            echo 'Diese E-Mail-Adresse ist bereits vergeben<br>';
            $error = true;
        }    
    }
    
    //Keine Fehler, wir können den Nutzer registrieren
    if(!$error) {    
        $passwort_hash = password_hash($passwort, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
        
        $statement = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO users (email, passwort) VALUES (:email, :passwort)");
        
        $result = $statement->execute(array('email' => $email, 'passwort' => $passwort_hash));
        
        if($result) {        
            echo 'Du wurdest erfolgreich registriert. <a href="login.php">Zum Login</a>';
            $showFormular = false;
        } else {
            echo 'Beim Abspeichern ist leider ein Fehler aufgetreten<br>';
        }
    } 
}
```

Login.php

```
type<?php 
session_start();
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydb11', 'root', '');
 
if(isset($_GET['login'])) {
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $passwort = $_POST['passwort'];
    
    $statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = :email");
    $result = $statement->execute(array('email' => $email));
    $user = $statement->fetch();
        
    //Überprüfung des Passworts
    if ($user !== false && password_verify($passwort, $user['passwort'])) {
        $_SESSION['userid'] = $user['usersID'];
        die('Login erfolgreich. Weiter zu <a href="geheim.php">internen Bereich</a>');
    } else {
        $errorMessage = "E-Mail oder Passwort war ungültig<br>";
    }
    
    
    
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head>
<title>Login</title>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">



</head>
<body>
 
    
    
    <form action="?login=1" method="post">
E-Mail:<br>
<input type="email" size="40" maxlength="250" name="email"><br><br>
 
Dein Passwort:<br>
<input type="password" size="40"  maxlength="250" name="passwort"><br>
 
<input type="submit" value="Abschicken">
</form> 
 


<?php 
if(isset($errorMessage)) {
    echo $errorMessage;
}
?>
 
 

</body>

<footer>

</footer>



</html>
```

geheim.php

```
<?php 
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydb11', 'root', '');
if(!isset($_SESSION['userid'])) {
    die('Bitte zuerst <a href="login.php">einloggen</a>');
}

$statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) AS anzahl FROM users");
$statement->execute();  
$row = $statement->fetch();
echo "Es wurden ".$row['anzahl']." User gefunden";





?>
```

I tried some solutions but they doesnt help with my problem. Hope you can help me.

Comment: (1) What do you expect if the user logs out ? (2) What do you expect if the user closes his/her browser without logging out ?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I edited the "geheim.php" . Its not possible to go to the "geheim.php" before the user is logged in.

Comment: This might be ok for a school project, but you should not store passwords in plain text in the database. That's inherently unsafe.